# Loops inside sql queries node js

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js

i want to write a code that selects addresses from a data base, try to call each adresse and insert coming  data into a new data base. Here is my code :

```
server.get('/room1',(req,res)=>{
    
    var pl = "room1"
    var sql = " SELECT*FROM "+pl;
    
    connection.query(sql,function (error, results) {
        if (error) throw error;
        while(true){
            for(var i=0 ; i<results.lenght; i++){
                console.log(results)
                var ip = "http://"+results[i]["IP"]
                console.log(ip)
                var msr = results[i]["Mesurement"]
                console.log("ok")
```

but due to the async in node js the programme stuck in the while loop.
My question is how can i replace loops inside the sql query?

Comment: Try `async.auto` or `async.each`

Comment: Isn't your while loop supposed to be an endless loop? I mean this part ```while(true)``` ?